# Is there a way to retreive labels of edges in jsplumb asynchronously, cuz I get undefined when I subscribe to observable to get data labels of edges

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, jsplumb

[image: 1]

in place of +N (I wanna get data from backend and put it as label of edges)

can you please help me to fix that issue ?
thanks to all

get jsplumb graph labels of edges asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

You can get an overlay by its id from a connection:

```
const o = someConnection.getOverlay("anOverlayId")
o.setLabel("new label value");
```

you set the ID for an overlay in the overlay options.

Comment: still not understanding how to update label when there is a filter or not (for example), I have another question, how params argument of label function filled , "label: (params) => {}" this? thank you

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "when there is a filter or not".